# moving files to equivalent folders in bash shell

Tags: bash, loops, shell

Im sorry for the very basic question but I am frankly extremely new at bash and can't seem to work out the below. Any help would be appreciated.

In my working directory '/test' I have a number of files named :

- mm(a 10 digit code)_Pool_1_text.csv
- mm(same 10 digit code)_Pool_2_text.csv
- mm(same 10 digit code)_Pool_3_text.csv

how can I write a loop that would take the first file and put it in a folder at :

```
/this/that/Pool_1/
```

the second file at :

```
/this/that/Pool_2/
```

etc

Thank you :)

Comment: Read the files in a loop (https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001, using `find`) and extract the pool number (`cut`, `sed` or `awk`), `mkdir` the directory, `mv` the file.

Comment: do the folders `/this/that/Pool_1`, etc, already exist?

Comment: yes, they do.  I just need to move the corresponding csv file into them.

Comment: Note that on Unix, BSD--and Linux, too--they are "directories" and not the Windows graphical concept of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Comment: :), offended?  No.  Check [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk` you many not need to create an explicit loop:

```
awk 'FNR==1 {match(FILENAME,/Pool_[[:digit:]]+/);system("mv " FILENAME " /this/that/" substr(FILENAME, RSTART, RLENGTH) "/")}' mm*_Pool_*.text.csv
```

- the shell glob selects the files (*we could use extglob, but I wanted to keep it simple*)
- awk gets the filenames
- we match pool and digit
- we move the file using the match to extract the pool name